# Сервер для работы с Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

В общем начал изучать Vue и вот вопрос.
К примеру я создал сервер на Node.js, который просто отправляет json

```
"use strict";

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req , res) => 
{
 res.writeHead(200 , { 'Content-Type': "application/json" });

let obj = {
name: 'Singlesly',
pass: '123'
};
res.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Установил шаблон vue начал писать компонент и вот незадача.
Как мне получить данные с сервера, если он находится на localhost:3000 , а vue на localhost:8080.
Нужно что бы я свободно получал данные ajax`om только проблема в том.
Как вообще настроить всю эту структуру, что бы можно было использовать ajax и брать данные с сервера. 
Рассмотрю любые варианты, даже интересно как вы работаете, потому что я вообще ничего не могу понять.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подгружать напрямую с другого сервера. Чтобы не было ошибки cross orgin, нужно отправить соответствующий заголовок. Этот вопрос обсуждался в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors) теме.

Кроме того, можно настроить webpack так, чтобы он в режиме реального времени генерировал итоговый html в указанную папку. Тогда можно обойтись одним сервером - тем, с которого получаете данные.

Как бонус, не придется прописывать глобальные пути для получения данных. Но вот страницу при этом придется обновлять каждый раз самостоятельно)) Ну, или смотреть gulp.